# Oracle SQL CASE condition = comparison not working properly?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this SQL,

```
  (CASE 
  WHEN CUST_TRANS.ADJ_IND = 'N' THEN 1
  ELSE 0
  END) AS test_N,
```

I have a line of records that has ADJ_IND (VARCHAR2) as 'N'. 
But the result of the CASE will always return 0, any idea why?

This is just a simple character comparison right?
Attached below are truncated(sensitivity)of the table structure. 
If you need more details, do let me know.

[image: TBL_CUST_TRANS]
[image]

Comment: If so, please check with `<>` as `CASE WHEN CUST_TRANS.ADJ_IND <> 'N' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END` lets check what will be the output ? and might be case sensitive issue try with small `n`

Comment: it's still 0. 
I have also tried to manually key in the value of  ADJ_IND as 'N' (without quotes), to eliminate the possibility it is not a character N previously.
I've also added UPPER(CUST_TRANS.ADJ_IND)

Comment: I can't say anything more unless seeing data and table structure.

Comment: @Susang, have added screenshots of data/table structure

Comment: @Hwee7 - Can you post your complete query.

Comment: `select adj_ind , count(*) from CUST_TRANS group by adj_ind `. Paste the output of this query.

Comment: @Hwee7 Posting complete query will help to analyze the result better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have your 'CASE' clause in the SELECT statement. The value fetched by ADJ_IND will depend on the WHERE Conditions of the SELECT Statement.
What I believe is happening here is, the SELECT query is fetching the value of 'ADJ_IND' as 'Y'. Therefore, your case clause is returning value as 0.

[image: Values in the table]

I did the same test case locally and the answer is coming as expected.
Below is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE tst_dum
(adj_ind VARCHAR2(1)); 
INSERT INTO tst_dum VALUES
('N');
SELECT * FROM tst_dum;
SELECT (
  CASE
  WHEN tst_dum.adj_ind = 'N'
  THEN 1
  ELSE 0
  END) AS test_N
FROM tst_dum;
```

[image: Attached the screenshot of the result.]

Comment: i went through the code, and found that it was one of the join statements that was causing this. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
(CASE CUST_TRANS.ADJ_IND 
 WHEN  'N' THEN 1
 ELSE 0
 END)
```

Let me know if it works.

---

This is the SQL fiddle I tried - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/afc78c/3